# Python: re.search not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my example. I am trying to search but nothing is printing on screen.

`DeltaE` is group 1
`TDMI^2` is group 2
`Intensity` is group 3

```
#   DeltaE =     0.0000 | TDMI^2 =  5.657    , Intensity = 0.5604E+06
    match = re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* TDMI^2 =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", line)
```

Comment: `^` is the *start of line* anchor, hence your regex matches nothing, unless `re.MULTILINE`. You need to escape it to match a literal `^`: `\^`.

Comment: use multiline instead search ?

Comment: Only if your input is on separate lines. But from what I can tell, your input is a single line. In that case, you simply need to escape the `^` to match a literal `^`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `^`  is a special char in regex, you must escape it in-order to match a literal carret symbol.

```
re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* TDMI\^2 =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", line)
```

Example:

```
>>> s = "DeltaE = 0.0000 | TDMI^2 = 5.657 , Intensity = 0.5604E+06"
>>> m = re.search(r"DeltaE =\s+(\S+).* TDMI\^2 =\s+(\S+).* Intensity =\s+(\S+)", s)
>>> m.group(1)
'0.0000'
>>> m.group(2)
'5.657'
>>> m.group(3)
'0.5604E+06'
>>> float(m.group(2))
5.657
>>> float(m.group(3))
560400.0
>>> float(m.group(1))
0.0
```

Comment: maybe u can help me a little more ?

Comment: i am using   tdmi = float(match.group(2)), but he gives me intensitie value, why is that ?

Comment: It's working fine for me . what's the output of `match.group(2)`?

Comment: then i am using this it says invalid literal for float and gives me group 3 number wtf

Comment: and also the traceback you got.. In your question not as an answer.

Comment: man i put it as answer because i dont want to missmatch my question with my new code, because others will get confused.

Comment: before converting group 1,2,3 try to print it out. What would be the output of those?

Comment: its printing ok , so i think it other part of my code is a mistake :)

Comment: replace `(\S+)` in the above regex with `([\w.]+)`

Comment: thanks, but i inserted  (   ,  )    this was a mistake : like this:  (\S+),